# JavaFX Scene Builder ScrollPane scrolls only few pixels

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have a small database that adds labels to a VBox, which is in AnchorPane, which belongs to ScrollPane. Technically, it works fine, except that the scroll movement is minimal. Moving from top to bottom of the scroll bar is only few dozen pixels in movement.

I have tried chaning all the settings in properties in layout menu and nothing ever happens, except that it sometimes break and inverts the direction of scrolling.

What should I do to make scrollpane scroll much more?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <ScrollPane layoutX="100.0" layoutY="52.0" pannable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vmax="100.0">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <children>
                <Label text="Label">
                  <font>
                    <Font size="50.0" fx:id="x1" />
                  </font>
                </Label>
                <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
                <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
                <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
                <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </ScrollPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Add a sample to reproduce the issue.  If your UI is FXML, create a minimal FXML to reproduce the issue which could be opened in SceneBuilder, if it is not FXML, then provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended fix to your sample FXML:

1. Don't set `vmax` on the vertical scroll.
2. Add in more content (e.g. more labels), so there is actually something to scroll.
3. Don't place the VBox holding your scrollable content inside an AnchorPane.

---

Try this version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <ScrollPane layoutX="100.0" layoutY="52.0" pannable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <Label text="Label">
        <font>
          <Font size="50.0" fx:id="x1" />
        </font>
      </Label>
      <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
      <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
      <Label font="$x1" text="Label" />
      <Label font="$x1" text="Label" /><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/><Label font="$x1" text="Label"/>
    </VBox>
  </ScrollPane>
</AnchorPane>
```